# Unable to connect with database with manual settings in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, database-connection, mariadb

The project were I'm working needs connect with multiple databases on runtime to this, I'm setting the connection propertie on the fly, I'm doing this as follows:

I create a helpers

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

if(! function_exists('conexionBD')){

    /**
     * Establish a tenant database connection.
     *
     * @param $hostname
     * @param $username
     * @param $password
     * @param $database
     */

    function conexionBD($hostname, $username, $password, $database){
        DB::purge('empresa');

        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.host', $hostname);
        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.database', $database);
        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.username', $username);
        Config::set('database.connections.empresa.password', $password);

        DB::reconnect('empresa');

        Schema::connection('empresa')->getConnection()->reconnect();
    }
}
```

I created a Middleware called Tenant

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (($request->session()->get('empresaId')) === null)
            return redirect()->route('inicio')->withErrors(['error' => __('Por favor inicie sesión en alguna empresa antes de intentar esta acción')]);

        $empresa = new empresa();
        $empresa->connect();

        return $next($request);
    }
```

My model of empresa is like that

```
class empresa extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'hostname',
        'username',
        'password',
        'database'
    ];

    public function connect()
    {
        if (! $this->connected()) {
            conexionBD(
                $this->hostname,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->database
            );
        }
    }

    private function connected()
    {
            $connection = Config::get('database.connections.empresa');
            return $connection['username'] == $this->username &&
            $connection['password'] == $this->password &&
            $connection['database'] == $this->database;
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this code, I get "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)" error, in my database config I have the database, username, password and host empty. In my database, in the empresas table I have that fields with correct information, but at the moment of change the database, the system tell me that, and I don't understand why if I'm not have a localhost user and my database has a password

Someone knows that my code is missing or that I am doing wrong to make the multi-tenant system work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check your .env file in root directory and set database value as shown in the example

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: The .env file is setted in the right way, with all the values, the problem is other, but thanks for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can change the connection at model level.
I hope it helps.

```
class ModelOnOtherDB extends Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = "other_db";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

the connection "other_db" should be configured on config/database.php

**Other solution**

A possible solution to change connection

```
public static function table($table, $bd) {
    return DB::table($table)->connection($db);
}
```

But you need all conections on condig/database.php :(

Comment: but, how can this work if I am using multi-tenants? for example, I have 20 databases, and all databases have a client table, in this case, this can it work?